# Apk not installing

Tags: android, apk

I'm trying to install Apk but it shows me this error.[image]

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Comment: You should ask for `app-release.apk`

Comment: I think you are tapping on the pdf file and you have not installed any pdf app on your mobile phone. Just install a pdf viewer on your mobile and that message should not appear anymore after tapping on pdf files.

Comment: it's not a programming question but the application i developed is not installing on other device it gives this error

Comment: Tap to open on the file explorer of your mobile phone and try again.

Comment: If you want to distribute your Android application, you should use the [Google Play Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tap to open on the file explorer of your mobile phone and try again.